# MySQLi bind_param UPDATE not working with empty value

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have the following MySQL query that appears sound but wont update the table when one variable is empty

```
$stmtEmploymentDetails = getDB()->prepare(
    'UPDATE EmploymentDetails SET BranchOffice=?, EmploymentDate=?, EmploymentStatus=?, EmploymentType=?, OrdinaryHours=?, JobClassification=?, ManagmentGroupID=? WHERE EmployeeID=?'
);
```

and the binding param

```
$stmtEmploymentDetails->bind_param(
    'ssiiisss',
    $branchOffice,
    $employmentDate,
    $employmentStatus,
    $employmentType,
    $ordinaryHours,
    $jobClassification,
    $managmentGroupID,
    $employeeID
);

$stmtEmploymentDetails->execute;
```

I have also tried using `COALESCE` but the value (I'm assuming) is empty not null

```
$stmtEmploymentDetails = getDB()->prepare(
    'UPDATE EmploymentDetails SET BranchOffice=COALESCE(BranchOffice=?, BranchOffice), EmploymentDate=COALESCE(EmploymentDate=?, EmploymentDate), EmploymentStatus=COALESCE(EmploymentStatus=?, EmploymentStatus), EmploymentType=COALESCE(EmploymentType=?, EmploymentType), OrdinaryHours=COALESCE(OrdinaryHours=?, OrdinaryHours), JobClassification=COALESCE(JobClassification=?, JobClassification), ManagmentGroupID=COALESCE(ManagmentGroupID=?, ManagmentGroupID) WHERE EmployeeID=?'
);
```

This same approach works without any problems on a smaller query with

```
$stmtEmployeeProfile = getDB()->prepare(
    'UPDATE EmployeeProfiles SET AKAName=? WHERE EmployeeID=?'
);
```

and

```
$stmtEmployeeProfile->bind_param(
    'ss',
    $AKAName,
    $employeeID
);

$stmtEmployeeProfile->execute();
```

But in that query the values are always supplied.
Anyone know where the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you put any error reporting around the query to see what is actually happening?

```
if ($stmtEmploymentDetails = getDB()->prepare(
'UPDATE EmploymentDetails 
 SET BranchOffice=?, EmploymentDate=?, 
 EmploymentStatus=?, EmploymentType=?, 
 OrdinaryHours=?, 
 JobClassification=?, 
 ManagmentGroupID=? 
 WHERE EmployeeID=?')) { 
    $stmtEmploymentDetails->execute(); 
 } else {
 echo "Failed prepare statement" . $this->conn->error . $this->conn->error;
 }
```

I hope that helps a little bit, when you have this error then work from that. Could be an issue of spelling or you haven't done the correct checks for values being empty. Way of doing this is a simple isset() statement such as.

```
if (isset($stmtEmplotmentDetails)) {
// do something 
} else {
$stmtEmplotmentDetails = 0; // or default value e.g. "N/A"
}
```

Also thinking on from have you checked the datatypes are correct to corrospond with the database, you have strings and integers in your bind parameter query. Do they match up with the datatype within your database?

Comment: And if possible can you show the error that is coming up?

Comment: Just updated the question to clarify the issue. It will execute without warnings but won't update the table. I will look into adding something along the lines of "N/A", see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: If you don't have default values in it will always complain, just make sure you have the correct checks in for every circumstance e.g. null, empty, popluated or incorrect value

Comment: @JedHodson let me know if you have managed to sort out the issue :)

Comment: I implemented the error checking and the problem is that there aren't any errors returned. The query will execute successfully, but it won't update the rows. I'm adding in the empty value checking now, so I will report back once I've finished that.